PySerial write not respecting baudrate on Mac and Linux (but it does on Windows)
I'm attempting to write a byte stream to a serial device (EDIT: connected via USB) using PySerial in order to upload a file. The device manufacturer recently switched from a Teensy-based board to a STM32-based one. The code below works fine on the Teensy-based board, regardless of OS. With the STM32 board, however, the code works fine in Windows, but in MacOS and Linux, the data writes too fast. Rather than restricting itself to the defined baud rate, it just writes as fast as it can read. This results in the device not receiving the data and timing out the write operation.
Slightly simplified Python 3 code below:
import serial

_SERIAL_SETTINGS = {'baudrate': 115200, 
                    'bytesize': 8, 
                    'parity': 'N', 
                    'stopbits': 1, 
                    'xonxoff': False, 
                    'dsrdtr': False, 
                    'rtscts': False, 
                    'timeout': 3, 
                    'write_timeout': None, 
                    'inter_byte_timeout': None}

# port has been previously identified based on OS
ser = serial.Serial(port)
ser.applySettings(_SERIAL_SETTINGS)

# file has been passed in elsewhere
bytes_sent = 0
fname = os.path.basename(file)
report_every_n_bytes = 512

with open(file, mode='rb') as binary_file:
    # Command to let the device know to receive a file. Format: "WR=filename,size\n"
    cmd = b'WR=' + fname.encode('utf-8') + b', ' + str(file_size).encode('utf-8') + b'\n'
    ser.write(cmd)
    response = ser.readline() # device responds with "OK Write filename, size\n"
    byte = binary_file.read(1)
    print(f'{fname} - Data sent: {getHumanReadableSize(bytes_sent)} - Data remaining: {getHumanReadableSize(file_size - bytes_sent)} - Speed: 0.00B/s', end='', flush=True)
    start_time = time.time()
    while byte:
        ser.write(byte)
        ser.flush()
        # Current workaround is to manually sleep a given time on non-Windows systems
        # if platform.system() != 'Windows': time.sleep(0.000087)
        bytes_sent += 1
        byte = binary_file.read(1)
        if bytes_sent % report_every_n_bytes == 0:
            print(f'\r{fname} - Data sent: {getHumanReadableSize(bytes_sent)} - Data remaining: {getHumanReadableSize(file_size - bytes_sent)} - Speed: {getHumanReadableSize(bytes_sent/(time.time()-start_time))}/s   ', end='', flush=True)

    # final report out
    print(f'\r{fname} - Data sent: {getHumanReadableSize(bytes_sent)} - Data remaining: {getHumanReadableSize(file_size - bytes_sent)} - Speed: {getHumanReadableSize(bytes_sent/(time.time()-start_time))}/s           ')
    # Check response. Expected response is “OK, Write complete.”
    # Instead, I’m getting “ERROR Write Timed Out”
    response = ser.readline()
    print(response)

At the moment, I can force a delay between bytes using time.sleep() (as indicated in the comment above), but this has been iffy. Usually it works, but sometimes the device still hits a read timeout. And I think there may be some data corruption happening as well, but I can't verify that yet.
I've been banging my head against this for months. What am I missing?
I've tried changing the connection framing settings, but nothing seems to make a difference. I suspect it must be somehow related to the underlying device driver, but how? And what can I do about it?
Edit 0: fixed typo to correct ser.write(bytes) to ser.write(byte)
Edit 1: For more context, some of the things I've tried already (none worked):

Changing the baud rate to a lower value
Using chunked writes instead of single-byte
Enabling various flow control settings, individually and in combination
Changing values for parity and stopbits

Edit 2: More details added. Also, I’m not an expert on serial devices or microcontrollers. Far from it! I’m just doing my best to learn as I go along.

Device is connected via USB to a port on a PCB (sorry—this I certainly should have mentioned before!)
When the write operation is finished, I perform another ser.readline(). This is when I receive the Write Timout error from the device.
According to the device’s documentation, it produces this if it has been sent a WR command, has not received the specified amount of data, and has not received any new data in 10 seconds.
This happens every time, reproducibly, with no change to hardware or software setup aside from different OSes. It also happens on different machines with the same conditions as above.
I’ll post some sample output once I’m back in front of the machine.


where does bytes, the data to be written to the serial come from? If you are really writting one byte at a time, the mechanism you are using to fetch that byte should be shown. Also, try to post always complete, self contained examples in code.

Now, more related to your problem: did you try setting the serial for some speed lower than 115200?

@Jason Ramboz –
Your writing Rather than restricting itself to the defined baud rate, it just writes as fast as it can read indicates a misconception of what baud rate means. I'd suggest reading about this and as well about flow control.

@jsbueno - Typo in the script. I edited above. It should be ser.write(byte). It's read from the file with byte = binary_file.read(1). And yes, I did try setting a lower speed -- same result.

"the data writes too fast ... the device not receiving the data" - Instead of providing a description of what actually occurs, you're only telling us what you think happens. "the device still hits a read timeout" - How do you know this? What do you see? The two variables that affect the problem are (1) the OS and (2) the target device. So this isn't a SW issue that is on-topic for this site. When you switch to a different OS, are you rebooting the same PC and using the same host serial port, or are you using different PCs and different serial connections?

@sawdust The device prints a read timed out error message to the serial line, so I can definitely verify that, from the device's perspective, it is not receiving some or all of the expected data. You're right that what appears to be happening is that PySerial (or the underlying driver) writes the data faster than the device can read. If you have other suggestions for what could be happening, I'm open to it.

@sawdust As for the PC, I've tried using different PCs and also using a Windows VM on a Mac machine. I've had other parties verify the same behavior independently on Linux machines. All produce identical results. I can't see how it's not a software issue. The question is where in the software chain it is (my code? PySerial? Driver?) and if there's anything I can do about it.

So the device emits an "read timed out error message to the serial line". When, immediately or after X seconds of transfers? One time, or repeatedly? Is your program sharing the "serial line" with the console connection?  Maybe you should speed up the writes by your program since the receiver complains of a "timeout" (i.e. lack of data)? Try removing the ser.flush() statement in your code.

@sawdust Look, I’m not a serial expert. I don’t have the right vocabulary, but I’m trying to learn. Nothing else is using the connection anywhere. What I am trying to explain is that with no change in hardware or setup besides the OS, I am observing a certain phenomenon. It is repeatable and happens every time. It also happens on different PCs. I may be describing wrong what is actually happening—as I said, I’m open to alternate interpretations! The device writes the error message after its specified write timeout interval—about 10 seconds. I’ll edit the post with more detail.

"When the write operation is finished, I perform another ser.readline()." - There's nothing like this in the "slightly simplified ... code" you posted. Is this in the while loop or after it???

After. I’ll amend the code.


                   'xonxoff': False, 
                   'dsrdtr': False, 
                   'rtscts': False, 


You disable software ('xonxoff') as well as hardware flow control, hence ignoring the receiving device telling when its buffer threatens to overflow; you should enable at least one of them.

As far as I'm aware, the device I'm writing to doesn't implement any flow control. At least, that is what I'm told by the manufacturer. I have no control over any on-device implementation.

Also, this doesn't explain why the code works correctly on Windows, but not on other OSes.

Just for the sake of argument, I tried enabling each flow control method individually and in various combinations. No change in behavior.

Of course when the device is so poorly designed that it doesn't implement any flow control, you're out of options. - That the code works correctly on Windows is probably due to it executing slower than on other OSes.
